# Is encoding swift array of optionals possible?

Tags: arrays, swift, encode, option-type

I'd like to be able to encode a class with an array of optional values. Xcode errors with "Cannot invoke 'encode object' with an argument list of type '([SKSpriteNode?], for key: String').

```
 class MyCustomNode: SKNode {

     var possibleSprites:[SKSpriteNode?] = [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

 ...

 }

override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encodeObject(self.possibleSprites, forKey: "POSSIBLESPRITES")
    super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)

}
```

Is this possible to achieve? If not, what are other options?

---

Question on proper decoding...

With the following,

```
 let x:[AnyObject!] = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("POSSIBLESPRITES") as! [AnyObject]
 self.possibleSprites = x.map { $0 == NSNull() ? nil : $0 }
```

I get Xcode error: “Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'”

I believe it has to do with the return type, but not sure how to solve...

Comment: How about var a:[AnyObject] = [NSNull(),NSNull()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Objective-C you can't encoding a nil pointer either. You need to map `self.possibleSprites` to an array of `AnyObject?` and use `NSNull` in place of nil.

```
let x : [AnyObject!] = self.possibleSprites.map { $0 == nil ? NSNull() : $0 }
aCoder.encodeObject(x, forKey: "POSSIBLESPRITES")
```

Just remember to decode it properly on the way back.